# Java Generics, defining a signature for a method that returns a specific Enum value

Tags: java, generics, enums

I have some code I want to write, roughly like this:

```java
public enum Type {
    Small,      
    Medium,
    Large;
}


public class ColumnType<T extends Enum<Type>> {
    //implementation not important
}


public abstract class Driver {
    //other stuff

    public abstract ColumnType<Type.Small> typeSmall();
    public abstract ColumnType<Type.Medium> typeMedium();
    public abstract ColumnType<Type.Large> typeLarge();
}
```

Basically I want to force the implementation subclasses of `Driver`, to provide method implementations which return a very specific type. These three abstract methods don't work as written, IDE says "unknown class" over the method signatures, if I remove the ".Small" and ".Medium" and just use `Type` all by itself in the Driver class methods, then it works. I've checked all the imports, I'm using the correct `Type` enum/class.

I usually don't get this deep in the weeds with Java's generics, is this type of thing supported? How would I force a child class to return specific `ColumnType` objects using enums? It's not enough that they return a `ColumnType`, I need them to return a `ColumnType` of a specific `Type`.

I've tried a few variations of this, this one kinda looks cleanest and like it should work so I'm leaving it here to get the question across.

Comment: What is `ColumnType<Type.Small>` supposed to *mean*? That's like saying `List<123>` or `List<"some string">`, which makes no sense.

Comment: Perhaps you should make `Type` a sealed interface, and write `Small`, `Medium` and `Large` as classes that implement `Type`? The three classes can all be singletons.

Comment: `Small`, `Medium` and `Large` are not *types*. They are *values* of the type `Type`. You cannot use values for type parameters.

Comment: It perhaps doesn't make sense from a compiler perspective (hence the question), but it makes sense conceptually. In the same way that jdbc has Types (BIT, VARCHAR, INTEGER) represented as integer values, I want these types to be the same sort of thing but statically checked at compile time so that classes can't just make up their own values and have it compile and "run".

Comment: What is the use case for this?  Sounds like a possible [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: @WJS perhaps just don't leave useless comments, this isn't a place to get into the use case.

Comment: @localdevjs  Perhaps you should be more polite to folks who are taking time to help you.   It is not useless and it **is** the place to get into it.  You're asking how to do something that won't compile without explaining how it will be used. This along with what appears to be confusion about enums suggests that there may be an alternative that you hadn't considered.

Comment: @WJS You left help? Your comment is the poster child for reason #1 on why I usually avoid this place.

Comment: @localdevjs I was soliciting Information about what your use case to see if there may have been a better alternative.  But you never complied.  Why are you so angry?

Comment: @WJS The other poster here got the gist of the question perfectly fine while suggesting an alternative. There is not enough time in the world to always leave a 300 page essay on what the problem is, the surrounding context, what has been tried etc. This question was already heavily reduced to as few lines as possible, it's not that hard to understand the question. Either I missed some capability/syntax on how to do what I wanted to do, or, it was not possible. I got the answer, all I needed was some confirmation that what I wanted to do wasn't supported.

Comment: *`There is not enough time in the world to always leave a 300 page essay on what the problem is, the surrounding context, what has been tried etc.`*   Well, I wasn't asking for all of that.  But I'm glad you got it resolved to your satisfaction.  Have a nice day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(For this answer, I will rename `Type` to `Size`, to avoid possible confusion with `java.lang.reflect.Type`, and "types" as a programming language concept)

I *suspect* what is happening here is that `ColumnType` has a field of type `T` (let's call this field `size`), and you want to require that each of those abstract methods return a `ColumnType` with its `size` field set to a specific value. For example, `typeSmall` must return a `ColumnType` with `size` equal to `Small`.

This is not possible with your current design, because the size of a `ColumnType` is not expressed in its type. `Small`, `Medium` and `Large` are not *types*. They are all just *values* for the single type `Size`. There is no such thing as `ColumnType<Size.Small>` for the same reason why there is no such thing as `List<123>` or `List<"some string">`. `123`, `"some string"`, and `Size.Small` are all *values*.

To achieve this, you would need to make `Small`, `Medium` and `Large` *types*. They should all have `Size` as a super type. I would make `Size` a `sealed interface`, as it maintains the exhaustiveness-checking that enums have.

```
sealed interface Size permits Size.Small, Size.Medium, Size.Large {
    final class Small implements Size {
        private Small() {}

        public static final Small INSTANCE = new Small();
    }
    final class Medium implements Size { ... } // similar to Small
    final class Large implements Size { ... } // similar to Small
}
```

Here, `Small`, `Medium` and `Large` are all singleton classes, making it easy to also get them as *values*. You'd say `Size.Small.INSTANCE` for example.

Now `ColumnType` and `Driver` can be rewritten as:

```
class ColumnType<T extends Size> {
    private final T size;

    public ColumnType(T size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public T getSize() {
        return size;
    }
}

abstract class Driver {

    public abstract ColumnType<Size.Small> typeSmall();

    public abstract ColumnType<Size.Medium> typeMedium();

    public abstract ColumnType<Size.Large> typeLarge();
}
```

To represent a `ColumnType` with an unknown size, you would use `ColumnType<?>`, and you can check its size either by checking the type of `size` using `instanceof`, or you can just compare using `==` with one of the `INSTANCE`s. Just like an enum, you can also use a `switch` to exhaustively check the 3 cases.

That said, you do lose some functionality of an enum, like `values()`, `name()`, `ordinal()` etc. You can work around this to an extent, by introducing an additional enum and a mapping method in `ColumnType`:

```
enum SizeEnum {
    SMALL, MEDIUM, LARGE
}

public SizeEnum getSizeAsEnum() {
    return switch(size) {
        case Size.Small x -> SizeEnum.SMALL;
        case Size.Medium x -> SizeEnum.MEDIUM;
        case Size.Large x -> SizeEnum.LARGE;
    };
}
```

Comment: This is getting a little ugly and I hate ugly code. Not saying its your fault and that it can be improved, it might just be something I have to live with I guess.

Comment: @localdevjs If you don't need anything enum-specific, you don't need the `SizeEnum`. And without `SizeEnum`, I don't think the code is particularly ugly. The singletons are a bit of boilerplate, sure, but I wouldn't call that "ugly".

Comment: The enum is used all over the place, so it has to stay. I'll think about it over the next day or so and if I end up using the class idea I'll circle back and accept your answer. Appreciate the idea.

Comment: @localdevjs I see. I had assumed that you were working on a new project. If you are working with existing code, then yeah, I don't think you can avoid this.

Comment: I accepted your answer as I believe it would work, however I will just not write the Driver to force the enum in the method return as I prefer that over the answer here. Again appreciate the suggestion.